# Create and Manage Sharepoint DocumentSet with MS Graph

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I can't find any way to create a documentset in Sharepoint Library using MS graph. Is there a way to do it? any help is mostly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no straight forward API today that you can leverage to achieve this.
Being said that, you can try this workout and see if this helps -

1. Get document library's drive id.

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/lists/${listId}?$expand=drive](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$%7BsiteId%7D/lists/$%7BlistId%7D?$expand=drive)

2. Create folder.

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/${library.drive.id}/root/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/$%7Blibrary.drive.id%7D/root/children)

Request body

```
{
    "name": "New Folder name",
    "folder": {},
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}
```

3. Get SharePoint item id for created folder.

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/drives/${library.drive.id}/items/${folder.id}?expand=sharepointids](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$%7BsiteId%7D/drives/$%7Blibrary.drive.id%7D/items/$%7Bfolder.id%7D?expand=sharepointids)

4.Update the item in the Document Library so that it updates to the desired Document Set.

PATCH [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/lists/${listId}/items/${sharepointIds.listItemId}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$%7BsiteId%7D/lists/$%7BlistId%7D/items/$%7BsharepointIds.listItemId%7D)

Request body

```
{
  "contentType": {
    "id": "content-type-id-of-the-document-set"
  },
  "fields": {
    //fields that you wish to set
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to complete this in the following way, sorry for not updating eariler:

Vars:

```
 SpURL = "site.sharepoint.com";
 SiteURL = "/sites/myTestSite";
 LibraryName = "Library";
 ContentType = "mycontenttype";
```

1- Get Site ID By Path:

```
var scopes = new string[] { ISD.MicrosoftGraph.Constants.ScopeDefault };
var client = GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(() => AcquireAppToken(scopes), "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta");
var site = await client.Sites.GetByPath(siteURL, spURL).Request().GetAsync();
return site.Id;
```

2- Drive ID by Path:

```
var scopes = new string[] { ISD.MicrosoftGraph.Constants.ScopeDefault };
var client = GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(() => AcquireAppToken(scopes), "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta");
var request = client.Sites[siteID].Drives.Request();
var result = await request.GetAsync();
//.Filter is not working here for some reasone
var filter = result?.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(LibraryName)).ToList();
if (filter.Count > 0) {
   return filter.First().Id;
}
else {
   return "";
}
```

3- Get List ID:

```
var scopes = new string[] { ISD.MicrosoftGraph.Constants.ScopeDefault };
var client = GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(() => AcquireAppToken(scopes), "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta");

var request = client.Sites[siteID].Lists.Request().Filter($"displayName eq '{ListName}'");
var result = await request.GetAsync();
return result.First().Id;
```

4. List ID:

```
var scopes = new string[] { ISD.MicrosoftGraph.Constants.ScopeDefault };
var client = GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(() => AcquireAppToken(scopes), "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta");
var request = client.Sites[siteID].Lists.Request().Filter($"displayName eq '{ListName}'");
var result = await request.GetAsync();return result.First().Id;
```

5. Add new folder:

```
var scopes = new string[] { ISD.MicrosoftGraph.Constants.ScopeDefault };
var client = GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(() => AcquireAppToken(scopes), "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta");
var folder = new DriveItem
{
    Name = foldername,
    Folder = new Microsoft.Graph.Folder(),
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename"}
    },
   
};
var folderObj = await client.Drives[driveID].Root.Children.Request().AddAsync(folder);
return folderObj.Id;

//Save folderID from the above return
```

6. contentType ID:

```
var scopes = new string[] { ISD.MicrosoftGraph.Constants.ScopeDefault };
var client = GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(() => AcquireAppToken(scopes), "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta");

var request = client.Sites[siteID].Lists[listID].ContentTypes.Request().Filter($"name eq '{contentTypeName}'");
var result = await request.GetAsync();
return result.First().Id;
```

7. List Item ID:

```
var scopes = new string[] { ISD.MicrosoftGraph.Constants.ScopeDefault };
var client = GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(() => AcquireAppToken(scopes), "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta");

var request = client.Sites[siteID].Drives[driveID].Items[folderID].Request().Select("sharepointIds");
var result = await request.GetAsync();
return result.SharepointIds.ListItemId;
```

8. Set folder content type and Proprities:

```
var scopes = new string[] { ISD.MicrosoftGraph.Constants.ScopeDefault };
var client = GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(() => AcquireAppToken(scopes), "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta");

var listItem = new Microsoft.Graph.ListItem
{
    Fields = new FieldValueSet
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"Country", "Palestine"},
            { "My_x0020_Field", "2000"}//Custom field with spaces
        }
    }
    , ContentType = new ContentTypeInfo() {
        Id = "0x5465424879454894654564654F300A1C2CDC00E306F9F19B9654654654654" //this is a sample content type id acquired in step 6
    }
};

var request = client.Sites[siteID].Lists[listID].Items[listItemID].Request();
var result = await request.UpdateAsync(listItem);
```

Hope this helps someone